# Is there a way to not log specific syslog messages?

Tags: linux, logs, pam, syslog, rsyslogd

For example I have the following:

```
pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=997)
pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
```

The log files are being flooded with them and was wondering if there was a way to reduce this by not logging this.

It looks like this is just background noise from a session in use?

Comment: You've tagged this question with `rsyslogd`. The [rsyslog documentation](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/filters.html) has some examples that do exactly what you're asking (filtering out messages that contain a certain string).

Comment: rsyslog can absolutely filter messages, systemd-journald logs everything.